# Asynchronous server with NodeJs and boost::asio combination

Tags: node.js, sockets, asynchronous, boost, server

I have built a REST API feature for some server (written in C++) and for some technical limitations I used `NodeJs` and `C++` `boost::asio` library for that. Working principle is shown in the picture below

[image]

Basically `NodeJs` is waiting for a HTTP request. When `NodeJs` gets a request, it makes a simple string, opens a new socket connection via `net.connect()` and sends to main C++ server. C++ server gets that string, does some job and sends back response string via socket. And finally, `NodeJs` after getting response from C++ server, makes a HTTP response from that and send back to client, after which `net.destroy()` is called, for closing socket.

So `NodeJs` module is server for outer world clients, but it is also client for the C++ server i.e. `NodeJs`  module is some kind of proxy server.

Currently I use `boost::asio`'s synchronous model and everything works just fine, however server processes just one request at the same time! But now I'd like to switch to asynchronous model in order to support multiple requests at the same time. Thus, I have a question, if I switch to `boost::asio`'s asynchronous model (with `async_accept`, `async_read`, `async_write`...) will this allow C++ server to process multiple requests at the same time, if it has actual one client i.e. `NodeJs`?

I'm quite new to `NodeJs` and `Javascript`. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to get my hands dirty and try to switch to `boost::asio`'s asynchronous model.

Now everything works just fine and C++ server processes multiple requests simultaneously.